# How to add dialog/modal that asks if we want to delete something in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So i have been looking on internet for some kinda of dialog/modal in vuejs2 that pops up when exit is clicked, that asks us if we are sure that we want to leave. And when click yes, function is called , and when clicked no, nothing happens just dialog/modal is exited. I was not able to find anything on the vuejs.org.Im not using bootstrap and not using vutify. Any suggestions how this can be done, that popup should blackout the rest of the screen and poput in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to create your own dialog.

Here is a small component that I created for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/ew1c3z6u/

I'm really new to Vue.js but this should work:

```js
    var component =new Vue({
          el: '#dialog-container',
          methods:{
            show:(event)=> {
              component.visibility = true;
              // maybe you could ajest the position of the dialog here.
              // eg top, center etc
            },
            onSave:(event)=> {
                alert("save clicked")
              component.visibility = false;
            },
            onCancel:(event)=> {
                alert("cancel clicked")
              component.visibility = false;
            }
          },
          data: {
            buttons:[], // you could have a list a dynamic buttons here
            content:"this is the content of the dialog",
            visibility:false,
            title: 'this is the title of the dialog'
          }
        })
```

```css
    .dimBackground{
      background:black;
      opacity:0.5;
      z-index:90;
      position:fixed;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      left:0;
      top:0;
    }
    #dialog-container > #dialog
    {
       background:white;
       z-index:100;
       min-width:400px;
       min-height: 100px;
       border:1px black solid;
       display:inline-block;
       padding:0;      
       position:fixed;
       left:30%;
       top:30%;
       overflow-x:hidden;
       overflow-y:auto;
    }
    
    #dialog-container > #dialog > h1{
      width:99%;
      background:blue;
      color:white;
      margin:0;
      font-size:20px;
      padding-top:5px;
       padding-bottom:5px;
       padding-left:5px;
    }
    
    #dialog-container > #dialog > .content{
      padding:5px;
    }
    
    #dialog-container > #dialog > h1 > div{
     display:inline-block;
     float:right;
     position:relative;
     top:-3px;
     padding-right:5px;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-container">
  <input type="button" value="show dialog" v-on:click="show"  />
   <div class="dimBackground"  v-if=visibility>   </div>
   <div id="dialog" v-if=visibility>
   <h1>
   {{title}}
   <div>
    <button  v-on:click="onSave" >
      Save
    </button>
    <button v-on:click="onCancel">
      Cancel
    </button>
   </div>
   </h1>
   <div class="content">
       {{content}}
   </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ty for your answer,il aproove your answer, i used something similiar like this https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-modal-component?from-embed anyway ty for your try, when first button is clicked i just set to false show modal and when second button is clicked call function from parent with passed argument. and in that function i just set model to false after

Comment: Glad i could help, But the idea of my code is to help you create a component eg plugin like jquery  or react where you can use endlessly with a little difficulty. But since your are already happy with your the result that you did make then that is it.